# passing attributes down to child without using it in host component in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I was experimenting with angular and let's say have 3 components:

1. a "input" component that is basically a directive with a few prebuilt attributes and behavior.
2. a wrapper component that holds the input and add some html around it.
3. a grouping component that projects n children inside as in:

```html
<app-group>
 <app-input id="test1" name="Option 1" value="1"></app-input>
 <app-input id="test2" name="Option 2" value="2"></app-input>
 <app-input id="test3" name="Option 3" value="3"></app-input>
</app-group>
```

The app-input component ends up like:

```html
<div id="test1">
  <input type="checkbox" id="test1" ...>
</div>
```

You see the problem right? labels won't work and now I have two elements with the same id.
So, if use @Input and call the components as below, it works.

```html
<app-group>
 <app-input [id]="'test1'" [name]="'Option 1'" [value]="1"></app-input>
 <app-input [id]="'test2'" [name]="'Option 2'" [value]="2"></app-input>
 <app-input [id]="'test3'" [name]="'Option 3'" [value]="3"></app-input>
</app-group>
```

But that is not the api I wanted. I wanted this to work if the user passes normal attributes as well.
Any ideas how to make this work if the components props are just attributes?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "to work if the user passes normal attributes"?

Comment: I know angular does not make a distinction (they are all inputs and it is shown that way in angular devtools), but for some reason when you pass data with brackets it works, but attributes (anything without brackets) it will be placed in the host as well. which I don't get why. I can remove the attribute from the host, but I wanted pass it down and simply not use it. not sure it is possible.